# Defining inventory variable using task output

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am currently trying to attach AWS Firehose to a log group of a dynamically created API Gateway.

The playbook runs these roles:

- role: api-gateway (creates the API Gateway and attaches it to Cloudwatch)
- role: firehose (connects the Cloudwatch logs from the API Gateway above to Firehose

The Cloudwatch Log Group name looks like this:

```
API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_<api_gateway_id>/alee
```

The inventory file for the Firehose Ansible role would have to look something similar to this:

```
cloudwatch_log_group_name: "API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_{{ api_gateway_id }}/alee"
```

My question is, is it possible to somehow register the {{ api_gateway_id }} variable from the role that created the API Gateway?

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of [`set_fact:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/set_fact_module.html) and/or what have you already tried that is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Upon trying it out, inventory vars can indeed be dynamically defined from the output of a role that was run previously.